# Is it possible to save one json files that gets updated using API in a BLOB Storage

Tags: azure, api, postman, blob

My First question is can we use POST method in a BLOB storage to update existing file/json/text. I know images can be uploaded using PUT method but can i upload a json file and then update the contents of that file from API? I am new to this Azure BLOB Storage.

MY Second question is if it is possible could you show how it is done using POSTMAN.

I even know i could use cosmos db or Azure table storage for storing data in tabular format instead of BLOB but i want to know is this possible on BLOB storage.